# What is the equivalent of sess_count in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, sessions

As [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/224333#session_rename) explained:

> All session functions starting with `sess_*`, as well as `session_save_session()`, are now renamed to `drupal_session_*` or `_drupal_session_*`

I have to use `sess_count()` in my D7 module and naturally I used `drupal_session_count()` but I ended up having `Call to undefined function drupal_session_count()` fatal error. I also tried `_drupal_session_count()` with no luck. 
[User session handling functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/7) page for Drupal 7 didn't mention about this function neither.
Which function should I use in order to count how many users have sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal_session_count()` was [removed from Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/655212). I'm not sure what an equivalent would be other than writing your own function.

Looks like the user block [has it's own](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_block_view/7) query. And admin menu [had to replace it](http://drupalcode.org/project/admin_menu.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/admin_menu.module#l338) too.

Answer (score 1):

The `drupal_session_count()` was removed in drupal 7, but I suppose you could do a simple `db_query` like this:

```
 $session_count = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {sessions}")->fetchColumn();
```

You could also look at the `drupal_session_count()` function and use something similar:

```
function drupal_session_count($timestamp = 0, $anonymous = TRUE) {
   $query = db_select('sessions');
   $query->addExpression('COUNT(sid)', 'count');
   $query->condition('timestamp', $timestamp, '>=');
   $query->condition('uid', 0, $anonymous ? '=' : '>');
   return $query->execute()->fetchField();
}
```